# Trying to extract specific text and merge output with existing output

Tags: powershell

I want to extract text from a .txt file. The way the file is layed out is in this format (below first block). Optimally, I would like for the powershell script to take the content of username and votecount and output them side by side. With an integer of 25>= add the letter D beside it. With the output adding itself to a pre-existing output file. Say this week is week 1. And testuser voted 25 times. They should have the output "testuser" 25D. But say in week 2 they voted 24 times. Then it should be "testuser" 49D. However say they had 25 again. Output should then be "testuser" 50DD or 50D2?.. I have what I think should work as an initial baseline for the script which in itself doesn't work.. But combining an output with a pre existing output is beyond my capability. This needs to parse an entire txt file of some 100+ people. So imagine there's like an extra 100 users..

```
{
            "username": "testuser",
            "votecount": "42",
            "votesclaimed": "0",
            "lastvotetime": "2022-11-04 09:08:29",
            "steamid": "00000000000000000000"
        }
```

Below is what I am working with.

```
Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\--------\Desktop\votes.txt |
  ConvertFrom-txt | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobject] @{
       UserName = $_.username
       VoteCount = '{0}{1}' -f $_.votecount, ('', 'D')[[int] $_.votecount -gt 25]
    }
  } |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 C:\Users\---------\Desktop\outvotes.csv
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of a few people to see the exact format.  I've done this hundreds of times (if not thousands) and just seeing one piece of the file doesn't give enough info to write code properly.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/zWRq7G_cxaCG

Comment: What is `ConvertFrom-txt` or did you mean `ConvertFrom-Json` ? Can you add more examples to your current output in the question and what would the expected would be ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$match = Select-String -Path "c:\temp\test.txt" -Pattern '^\s*"(?<key>[^"]+)"\s*:\s*"(?<value>[^"]+)'
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach( $row in $match.Matches )
{
   $key = $row.Groups["key"].Value
   $value = $row.Groups["value"].Value
   if($key -eq "username") {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      $table.Add($newRow)   | Out-Null
   }
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $key -NotePropertyValue $value
}
$table | Format-Table
$groups = $table | Group-Object {$_.username}
```