# What are ways to convert JSON to CSV locally without any third party tools

Tags: json, sql-server, powershell, csv, command-line

Trying to find out if there is a way to convert JSON to CSV locally on my computer without installing any 3rd party tools or using the browser/website. Maybe there is a way to get it done in command prompt or PowerShell or using notepad++ or SQL Server. I have tried Microsoft Excel's get data from JSON function but it errors out because it didn't like some characters in the JSON file. Thank you.

Comment: PowerShell has both `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Csv` (along with `Export-Csv`). Depending on the shape of your data you may still need to manipulate it a bit (CSV doesn't support nested objects). SQL Server probably won't be of any help to you -- while it can parse JSON, it can't write CSV files without really ugly hacks, so you'd still need to copy the output somewhere else first. (Besides, it's definitely a "third party tool", even if Microsoft also supplies your operating system.)

Comment: If you have invalid characters in your JSON you may well find any attempt to use it as  JSON will fail.

Comment: See: [Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081131/1701026)

Comment: Op didn't post entire file so I'm not sure if it was JSON.  So this is what I did : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336733/trying-to-extract-specific-text-and-merge-output-with-existing-output/74340341#74340341

Answer (score 1):

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) points out, `ConvertFrom-Json`, `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv` will most likely be the basis for your solution. Without knowing the structure of your JSON, which is the key factor in determining how you'll go about it, **here's an example** with some native OS data on Windows using PowerShell.

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name,Handles,VM,Description -First 3 | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File .\procs.json
$procs = Get-Content -Path .\procs.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$procs | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Out-File .\procs.csv
& .\procs.csv
```

In the code above, we...

1. Get an array of Windows process objects and create a JSON version of the data.
2. Convert the JSON data into an array of objects.
3. Convert the objects into a CSV.
4. Open the CSV with the default application, Excel in my case.

You should see a nicely formatted CSV with column headers and rows of data.